# Adding up the values ​of points in the designated polygon

Tags: qgis

I'm just getting started with QGIS. I have a layer of points with a specific value. How do I sum up the point values ​​in a designated polygon?

In the attachment screen:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can also use field calculator with an expression such as:

```
aggregate('points','sum',"vals",filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
```

where `points` is the name of your point layer and `vals` the fieldname containing the values. Apply this in the attribute table of your polygon layer via fieldcalculator.

Make sure both layers are in the same CRS as mentioned by @Babel.

To make this update automatically everytime you modify the polygon, you can add it as a virtual field. Simply check the box for that in fieldcalculator:

[image]

But note this attribute will only be available in your QGIS project. It is not stored permanently in your datasource!

[image]

Comment: OK, seems to work, but only if both layers are in the same CRS - if they are in differnt CRS, it doesn't work.

Comment: That can be true as it is an old expression which probably does not support on the fly reprojection, but its also working in QGIS 3.0 :)

Comment: 1. I have a layer with values ​​called <zach_pomor> with the structure: <address/pop/LAT/LTG>
2. I create a new temporary layer called <new_test>, geometry type <Polygon>, EPSG 4326 - WGS 84,
3. Draws a polygon
4. In the created layer, "open attribute tables".
I use expressions either:
<array_sum (overlay_contains ('west_pomor', "pop"))>
or
<aggregate('sach_pomor','sum',"pop",filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
>
, it actually counts my points from the designated area and it's great.

Comment: But how to do if I wanted to edit the range of the designated area and have it automatically count the value of <pop> contained in this zone.
Please help

Comment: about your second question on how to update the sum on every modification on your polygon, please see the updated answer about a virtual field or the answer for the virtual layer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/449796/107424

Answer (score 5):

You can use "Join Attributes by Location (summary)" from processing toolbox.

Choose the `polygon layer` as `input` and the `points` as `join layer`, your `field(s) to summarize` and `sum` as `summaries to calculate`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have tried this method so far but I have a few questions.
First, are you doing it right?
1. I have a layer with values ​​called <zach_pomor> with the structure: <address/pop/LAT/LTG>
2. I create a new temporary layer called <new_test>, geometry type <Polygon>, EPSG 4326 - WGS 84,
3. Draws a polygon
4. I run join attributes by location
5. "Join to features in" - <new_test>
6. "by comparing it" - <zach_pomor>
7. Total field - <pop>
8. Field to be calculated - <sum>
9. Run
10. A "join layer" is created, where I reveal the labels and select <pop_sum>

Comment: 2. Second:
Am I able to edit the temporary layer (e.g. by manually stretching the vertices) so that it immediately updates the <pop_sum> value?
thank you in advance for your help

Comment: about your second question on how to update the sum on every modification on your polygon, please see the updated answer about a virtual field: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/449573/107424 or the answer using a virtual layer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/449796/107424

Answer (score 4):

Create a new attribute field with [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) and this expression, using [`overlay_contains()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-contains) function (QGIS 3.18 or above):

```
array_sum (overlay_contains ('point_layer', "value"))
```

*Replace `point_layer` with the point layer's name and `value` with the field name of the attribute that contains the value you want to sum up.*

Comment: Maybe explain in a more verbose way _"Create a new attribute field in the polygon layer with .."_?

Comment: I will also ask for a hint on how to do it, I will be very grateful. Should I create a temporary layer by selecting the polygon where the points whose values ​​are to be summed are located?
Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 1):

You use a virtual layer with a query such as:

```
select pol.geometry, sum(poi.vals) as valsum from polygon as pol
join points as poi on ST_Intersects(pol.geometry,poi.geometry)
```

This will update every time you modify the polygon layer and recalculate the sum.